# Which types are the given functions?

Tags: c

These 2 are the functions.

```
double *f1 (double* p);
double (*f2) (double *p);
```

Which types are these two functions?

Comment: The first one is a function but the second one is not. The second one is a function pointer.

Comment: While it's easy to answer the question, I think it will be more helpful to add some context. What made you think about them? What do you think they are and why do you think that? Did you try to find an answer by yourself?

Answer (score 2):

The first is a function that returns a double pointer. The second is a function pointer, not a function.

The general syntax for a prototype for a function that returns a pointer is:

```c
<type> *<name>(<parameters>);
```

The general syntax for a function pointer, which is *not* a function but is a pointer *to* a function, is:

```c
<type> (*<name>)(<parameters>);
```

So what you have there, `double (*f2) (double *p);` is a function pointer that can point to a function that takes a `double *p` as an input and returns a `double` as an output. This is unlike `double *f1 (double* p);` which is a prototype for a function that takes a `double *p` as an input and returns a `double *` as an output.

Answer (score 0):

`f1` is a function that returns a pointer to `double`.  `f2` is a pointer to a function that returns `double`.

Each declaration is read as follows:

```
        f1                 –– f1
        f1 (         )     –– is a function taking
        f1 (        p)     ––   parameter p
        f1 (      * p)     ––   is a pointer to
        f1 (double* p)     ––     double
       *f1 (double* p)     –– returning a pointer to
double *f1 (double* p);    ––   double

         f2                –– f2
       (*f2)               –– is a pointer to
       (*f2) (         )   ––   a function taking
       (*f2) (        p)   ––     parameter p
       (*f2) (       *p)   ––     is a pointer to
       (*f2) (double *p)   ––       double
double (*f2) (double *p);  ––   returning double
```

Despite its appearance, `f2` is not a function - it’s a pointer that stores the address of another function.

In both declarations and expressions, the postfix `[]` subscript and `()` function call operators have higher precedence than unary `*`, so a declarator like `*f()` is parsed as `*(f())` and declares a function returning a pointer.  To declare a pointer to a function or a pointer to an array, you have to explicitly group the `*` operator with the identifier:

```
T *a[N];       // a is an array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N];     // a is a pointer to an array of T
T *f();        // f is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)();      // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```